# Is there a way  to compare networks in terms of internet connection?

Tags: connection-issues, data-connection

I want to compare two different networks and choose the "better one". Better could be that I want to find out if the one I want to switch to would handle VoIP applications, like a Skype call in particular.

Is there any way for me to compare two networks like this? I have two SIM cards and and an Android phone with CyanogenMod 7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always perform a speed test and check for packet loss( [Speedtest.net](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zwanoo.android.speedtest), [pingtest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=user51.testping.proc))

Alternatively, you can try calling the skype Voice Testing Service which should be in your contacts from before, and if it isnt there the username is echo123 i belive.

Comment: I was thinking more of something that would do more tests for me. If there is nothing else I will end up doing what you suggested.

Comment: I doubt there is an application that asks you to insert a SIM, make the test, then ask for the other one and perform the same tests.. what you can do is use the applications i suggested above and write down the results and compare them that way.. unless I have misunderstood what you meant by 'testing' ie. speed or link quality

Comment: Well quite often one can save test results. What I want to compare is speed, latency, link quality ...

Comment: The speedtest test speed, and pink
While the pingtest tests Jitter, Packetloss and overall link quality.. so i think these are the 2 applications you are looking for.. im not entirely sure if the pingtest app. is available on the play store

Comment: I got average of 13 tests download 50kbps and average upload 164kbps where max is 288 and min 10. Is that even possible that upload speed is higher than download speed? I always thought that it was the opposite way.

Comment: Speedtest.net got native android application by the way ;-)

Comment: @Radek , in some cases yes, although it is highly unlikely, especially since you are probably using a consumer package for 3G. Some factors to consider if you think you are getting low speeds are; try the speedtest out side, and also check the protocol on which your mobile is connecting with, as far as I know 3G's fastest is HSDPA which can support speeds up to 21mbps if im not mistaken. The speeds you posted are somewhat worrying even for 2g(GSM) standards. Make sure no other application is using the internet aswell.

Comment: I was more pointing out the fact that upload is higher than download. I think that the download was "OK" considering all circumstances.